# To check whether all elements of a `Stream` are identical

Tags: java, java-8, predicate, java-stream

I am in the process of changing some of my old code to take advantage of the functional aspects of Java 8. In particular, I am moving from using Guava predicates to `java.util.function.Predicate`. One of the predicates is to check whether a `Stream` is homogeneous, i.e. consists of all identical elements.

In my old code (using Guava's `Predicate`), I had this:

```
static <T> Predicate<Iterable<T>> isHomogeneous() {
    return new Predicate<Iterable<T>>() {
        public boolean apply(Iterable<T> iterable) {
            return Sets.newHashSet(iterable).size() == 1;
        }
    };
}
```

This is the new version, using `java.util.function.Predicate`:

```
public static Predicate<Stream<?>> isHomogeneous =
    stream -> stream.collect(Collectors.toSet()).size() == 1;
```

The IDE (IntellijIDEA v.12) doesn't show any red squiggly line to indicate an error, but when I try to compile, I get this:

```
java: no suitable method found for
collect(java.util.stream.Collector<java.lang.Object,capture#1 of ?,java.util.Set<java.lang.Object>>)
  method java.util.stream.Stream.<R>collect(java.util.function.Supplier<R>,java.util.function.BiConsumer<R,? super capture#2 of ?>,java.util.function.BiConsumer<R,R>) is not applicable
    (cannot infer type-variable(s) R
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
  method java.util.stream.Stream.<R,A>collect(java.util.stream.Collector<? super capture#2 of ?,A,R>) is not applicable
    (cannot infer type-variable(s) R,A,capture#3 of ?,T
      (argument mismatch; java.util.stream.Collector<capture#2 of ?,capture#4 of ?,java.util.Set<capture#2 of ?>> cannot be converted to java.util.stream.Collector<? super capture#2 of ?,capture#4 of ?,java.util.Set<capture#2 of ?>>))
```

**Note:** I think having a predicate on a stream is probably not a good idea. In fact, in my codebase, I only need it on a `List<>`. But I am still curious about what is wrong with the simple one-line `isHomogeneous` predicate.

Comment: Works in eclipse. Try with the Oracle compiler.

Comment: This could be solved lazily with an `allMatch` (or a `reduce`, but not lazily) without needing a Set at all.

Comment: Try changing method name `apply` to `test`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Another option is to use `Stream.distinct` and make sure you only get 1 element in the resulting stream.

```
stream.distinct().limit(2).count() == 1
```

Comment: `distinct().limit(2).count()` to avoid unnecessary item processing as it doesn't matter if count is `2` or more than two here. So the stream can stop when encountering the second distinct item.

Answer (score -1):

Probably what you want to do is using a method reference like

```
static <T> boolean isHomogeneous(Iterable<T> iterable) {
    return Sets.newHashSet(iterable).size() == 1;
}
```

and then you can use it like that

```
Iterable<Integer> iterable1 = Lists.newArrayList(1, 1);
Iterable<Integer> iterable2 = Lists.newArrayList(1, 2);

Stream.of(iterable1, iterable2).filter(YourClass::isHomogeneous).collect(Collectors.toList());
```